# Understanding why EagerTensor.numpy() is slow

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, tf.keras

I'm trying to make predictions using a pre-trained custom image segmentation model on some image data but I'm having problems with the predictions being too slow.
After doing some profiling using [Pyinstrument](https://github.com/joerick/pyinstrument) I found that the call to `numpy()` is what is taking up the majority of the running time.
This surprised me, as to my understanding all the function has to do is copy the predicted data from the GPU back to the host and perhaps do some other things to convert the data to a numpy-array.

I produced a minimal working example which shows the effect:

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from pyinstrument import Profiler

model = tf.keras.applications.resnet50.ResNet50(include_top=False, input_shape=(672, 2048, 3))
data = np.zeros((1, 672, 2048, 3))

profiler = Profiler()
profiler.start()

for _ in range(1000):
    prediction = model.predict_on_batch(data)
    output = prediction.numpy()

profiler.stop()
print(profiler.output_text())
```

The code produces the following Pyinstrument output:

```
  _     ._   __/__   _ _  _  _ _/_   Recorded: 15:50:54  Samples:  6759
 /_//_/// /_\ / //_// / //_'/ //     Duration: 56.536    CPU time: 56.406
/   _/                      v3.1.0

Program: test.py

56.536 <module>  test.py:1
|- 42.315 numpy  tensorflow_core\python\framework\ops.py:918
|     [4 frames hidden]  tensorflow_core
|        39.179 _numpy  tensorflow_core\python\framework\ops.py:905
|- 12.667 predict_on_batch  tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training.py:1220
|     [7705 frames hidden]  tensorflow_core, ast, _weakrefset, we...
`- 1.553 [self]
```

I'm using Tensorflow 2.1.0 on an RTX 2080 Ti. The effect is even more pronounced when using my own model, in which case the call to `numpy()` takes up over 90 % of the running time.

I have also tried using `output = np.array(memoryview(prediction))` as mentioned in
[this comment](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/eba45c548371e29cd141c32d367b582b9ca656be/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py#L954)
but with no significant difference in performance.

Could someone please explain why this happens? Is this the expected behaviour? Is the output not completely ready immediately after the call to `predict_on_batch()`, so `numpy()` has to wait for the output to be ready before creating an array from it?

**Update:** By adding a `time.sleep(0.1)` between the calls to `predict_on_batch()` and `numpy()` in the example code I get this output instead:

```
  _     ._   __/__   _ _  _  _ _/_   Recorded: 12:03:52  Samples:  7821
 /_//_/// /_\ / //_// / //_'/ //     Duration: 135.388   CPU time: 25.641
/   _/                      v3.1.0

Program: test.py

135.388 <module>  test.py:1
|- 105.639 [self]
|- 16.191 numpy  tensorflow_core\python\framework\ops.py:918
|     [4 frames hidden]  tensorflow_core
`- 13.558 predict_on_batch  tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training.py:1220
      [7839 frames hidden]  tensorflow_core, ast, _weakrefset, we...
```

As you can see, the time for `predict_on_batch()` is still roughly the same, but by waiting for a bit the time spent in `numpy()` is greatly reduced. To me, this seems to point toward my theory that the output is not completely ready when reaching `numpy()` so it has to wait for a bit before it can produce the array. I'm still not quite satisfied though, could someone shed some light on the situation? Is there anything that can be done to improve the performance?

Comment: "all the function has to do is copy the predicted data from the GPU back to the host" that is a (relatively) slow operation. Depending on your problem and model, you have to evaluate whether the gains of GPU computing (as opposed to CPU) is worth the additional overhead of moving things in and out of the GPU, specially for inference if you are only predicting on one input at a time.

Comment: @jdehesa Well yes, copying is an expensive operation. But the time to copy the data _to_ the device should be roughly the same as the time to copy data back from the device, right? In which case I would expect `predict_on_batch()` and `numpy()` to take roughly the same amount of time, or `predict_on_batch()` to take a bit more time since it is also doing the computations. Doing inference on the CPU in this case is completely infeasible, the model is far too big.

Comment: I am having this issue too. Right now I am trying converting the model to TensorRT, as well as [optimizing](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms/README.md#optimizing-for-deployment) the non-TensorRT SavedModel. If any of these work, I will post an answer with detailed steps. Have you made any progress in understanding the issue?

Comment: Unfortunately I have not managed to learn anything more about this. I would be very interested to see if you have any success.